# help with a tikz circuit

Tags: circuitikz

I'm new to this website and also new to using TeX. I've managed to draw basic circuits however the one attached is beyond my current skill level. Hoping someone can help out.

Cheers[image]

Comment: [Welcome to the site](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please show us what you have so far. This is not a 'please do it for me' site.

Comment: See [Help with my tikz circuit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207902/help-with-my-tikz-circuit) and [Transformers in Circuitikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207770/transformers-in-circuitikz).

Comment: The only tricky bits are the two boxes.  You can always use a tikz \node[draw=black,thick,inner sep=5mm] (name) at (x,y} {7805}; and connect to (name.east), (name.west) and (name.south).  And the center tapped transformer might be a problem.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Easy, it is often a do it for me place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way of doing it.  Explanations are scattered in the codes. Orthogonal coordiantes are used in many line connections/circuit elements allocations.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}  
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (0,0) node [scale=1.5,transformer core
] (T){}
      (T.A1) node[above] {A1}
      (T.A2) node[below] {A2}
      (T.B1) node[above left] {B1} 
      (T.B2) node[below left] {B2}
      (T.base) node{};
\path (T.B1) -| ++ (2,1) coordinate (tb1){};% define a coordinate at top right relative to B1
\draw (T.B1) -- ++ (0,1) to[D*,-*]  (tb1);      
\draw (T.B2) to[D*] ++(2,0)coordinate(tba){} -| (tba |- tb1);
\path (T.B2) |- ++(3,-1) coordinate(tb2){}; % define a coordinate at bottom right relative to B2
\draw (tb2) to[D*,*-] ++(-3,0) -- (T.B2);
\draw (tb2) --(tb2 |- T.B1) to[D*] (T.B1); 
% place voltage labels 
\draw(T.A1) to[open,v<={$240V_{rms}$,o-o}](T.A2);
\draw($(T.B1)!0.3!(T.B2)$) node[]{$12V_{rms,AC}$}(T.B1);
\draw ($(T.B1)!0.8!(T.B2)$)node[]{$12V_{rms,AC}$}(T.B2);
\draw[thick] ($(T.B1)!0.51!(T.B2)-(1cm,0)$)coordinate[](c){} -- ++ (12.44,0) -| ++ (1,-1) node[ground]{};                          % add a gorund to neutral line
% place capacitors and resistor (upper branches)
\draw(6,1) node[](d1){} to [C,l_=$C_1$, *-*] (c -| d1);
\draw(10,1)node[](d2){} to [C,l_=$C_3$, *-*] (c -| d2);
\draw(13,1)node[](d3){} to [R,l=$R_L$]       (c -| d3);
% place rectangles
\draw (7.5,0.5)  rectangle (8.5,1.5) node[below left= 0.25cm and 0.1cm]{780s}; 
\draw (7.5,-3.6) rectangle (8.5,-4.6)node[above left=0.25cm and 0.1cm]{790s};
% place capacitors and resistors (lower branches)
\draw(6,-4.15) node[](d4){} to [C,l_=$C_2$, *-*] (c -| d4);
\draw(10,-4.15)node[](d5){} to [C,l_=$C_4$, *-*] (c -| d5);
\draw(13,-4.15)node[](d6){} to [R,l=$R_L$]       (c -| d6);
\draw (8,0.5)  node[](d7){} to [short,-*]        (c -| d7) --(8,-3.6);
% place top and bottom lines
\draw(2,1) -- (7.5,1) (8.5,1) --(11,1) to[short,i^={$I_L$}] (13,1);
\draw(2,-4.15) -- (7.5,-4.15) (8.5,-4.15) --(13,-4.15);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```